# Do you know what this strange icon means

Tags: windows-10, icons

My windows 10 shows (I am mainly Linux user) shows strange icon over other icons:

[image]

What is it?

Comment: You like have an unidentified cloud synchronizing application installed on your system. So what software do you have installed that might fit that description?

Comment: @Ramhound Nothing to be honest. It is only on top of applications, but not data

Comment: And it has disappeared after few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon seems to be taken from SourceTree project. Please check whether you have SourceTree installed, and maybe some weird options in it enabled. If you don't have and never had it installed - maybe it's worth running an anti-virus scan, just in case.

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: Yes I have. Interesting why all program icons had it for a while.

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that - I've just got curious and found the app using Google image search) Maybe you could check on app forum...